# Resources for differential Galois theory for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am dealing with a PDE and I am trying to characterize the solutions: Galois differential theory might be of help, but I can only find books about this theory applied to ODE.

Are there resources, books or papers, on the application of Galois differential theory to partial differential equations?

I know the basis of the Galois differential theory applied to ODE as explained in Magid's *Lectures on differential Galois Theory* and *Galois theory of linear differential equations* by van der Put and Singer, and I am looking for something along the same lines, but maybe with more examples and at least at the graduate level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a specialist on these matters (despite the fact that I tried to dive deep in this subject when I was younger...) but I suspect that the only comprehensive approach to a Galois theory for PDEs (and system of PDEs) is the work of Jean Francois Pommaret [1]: thus the following answer is more a short description of that work that a real technical survey.
That said, let's start by quoting Pommaret himself ([1], p. 1) (the emphasis is due to the Author himself)

> .... As a result, at the end of the last century and at the beginning of this, many mathematicians had the dream of finding a *Galois theory for systems of partial differential equations*.
> *The purpose of this book is to provide for the first time the complete solution of this problem by means of new methods from differential and algebraic geometry.*.

The **main features** of the book are listed below.

- A brief historical sketch is provided in the "Introduction" ([1], pp 1-6). By reading it we learn that the theory developed by Pommaret is an extension and a correction of the theories of Charles-Emile Picard, Ernest Vessiot and Jules Drach as later developed by Ritt and Kolchin along the lines of Riquier and Janet. Relations with the works of Donald Spencer and Hubert Goldschmidt are also sketched.
- The approach is based on tools from differential and algebraic geometry: according to the Author ([1], p. 1), this is the main difference between the theory developed by him and his predecessors and the one developed by Picard, which is mainly based on algebraic and analytic tools. In particular

  1. Dealing with PDEs and systems of such equations, [Lie pseudogroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudogroup#Pseudogroups_and_Lie_theory) are naturally used instead of finite groups of Lie type.
  2. [Commutative diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram) and the [technique of diagram chasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram#Diagram_chasing) are systematically used as means for providing proofs of the presented results.
- The book is not an easy read. Nevertheless it is more readable than other works on the topic (and I say this from the point of view of an electronics engineer): the tools needed are introduced somewhat gently, the notation tries to be accessible and clear and moreover the Author gives a lot of historical insights, motivation and context for his work. Moreover, according to the Author ([1], p. 6)

  > This book has been written to be self-contained, and the thousand examples included will help the reader to develop the new method. The way to read it is clear from the table of contents.

**Reference**

[1] Jean-Francois Pommaret, *Differential Galois theory*, Mathematics and Its Applications, Vol. 15. New York-London-Paris: Gordon and Breach Science Publishers. VIII+759 (1983), [MR720863](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=720863), [Zbl 0539.12013](https://zbmath.org/0539.12013).

Comment: Thanks! I will wait a few days to see if anyone else wants to post an answer, then I will accept yours.

Comment: You are welcome, Mattia.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide any information about the PDE you're interested in, or what you mean by "characterize the solutions", it's hard to say whether or not differential Galois theory will help.

The issue with Pommaret's differential Galois theory is that it provides structural information about systems of PDEs, not necessarily properties of their solutions. In fact, Pommaret has consistently advocated this viewpoint (e.g. p. 118 of reference [1] in the accepted answer):

> *This shows that as far as possible we must avoid dealing with points,
> solutions and roots, but rather use systems and ideals in a systematic
> way.*

If you're interested in finding solutions, I suggest that Peter J. Olver's book *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations* (Springer, 1986 and 1993) might be more useful.